# Search large compressed logs

Tags: php, unix

I have 4 unix servers. In each servers there are 4 additional folders.  Inside each folder there are the `catalinaYYYYMMDD.out.bz2`.  We use these files to analyze customer activities, and each file is 300-400 MB.

I need to find a solution for quickly searching through customer's user id. The `bzcat` or `bzgrep` commands are too slow.

What do you suggest to do?  Is it possible to make it with PHP?

Comment: Hi there, maybe an example? About "I need to find a solution for quick search through customer's user id" part, how are you doing this actualy?

Comment: Hello! I usually write scripts in PHP that connect via SSH to servers and then call up unix commands (example: bzgrep <?= $Userid ?> Catalina - <?= $Year ?> - <?= $Month ?> - <?= $Day ?>. Out.bz2) as I need to develop a customer care tool (they do not have direct access to the servers). If the log files are not big this stratagem works, but in this case it does not work because the log files are too large. The structure is more or less the following:

Comment: Backend1 -> (logpath1 - logpath2 - logpath3 - logpath4)
Backend2 -> (logpath1 - logpath2 - logpath3 - logpath4)
Backend3 -> (logpath1 - logpath2 - logpath3 - logpath4)
Backend4 -> (logpath1 - logpath2 - logpath3 - logpath4)
When a user accesses in our systems, the transaction is accidentally logged in to one of the logpaths, so I need to find a way to speed up the searches...should I do this with the Hadoop framework?

Comment: Better title, better tags, copyedit question